# How to contract nodes that have only 2 edges in NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph in NetworkX that roughly is like this:

```
a---b---c---d
    |
    e---f
```

I want to simplify it, removing intermediary nodes that have only 2 edges.

```
a---b---d
    |
    f
```

How can this be done in NetworkX? I only see remove node methods, or contract edges. But this has to do with nodes instead.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54060830/3782865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
for node in list(G.nodes()):
    if G.degree(node) == 2:
        edges = list(G.edges(node))
        G.add_edge(edges[0][1], edges[1][1])
        G.remove_node(node)
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner version of @zohar.kom will be to use the subgraph method:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.random_graphs.watts_strogatz_graph(100, 3, .4)

threshold = 2
sub       = graph.subgraph([node for node in graph.nodes() if \
                            graph.degree(node) != threshold])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

nx.draw(graph, ax = ax[0], with_labels = 1)
nx.draw(sub, ax = ax[1], with_labels = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: 1. I assume you meant `[node for node in graph.nodes() if graph.degree(node) != threshold]`, otherwise we'll get only the nodes to remove, instead of the nodes we actually want.
2. This is not enough, since you only remove the relevant nodes, which is great, but you also need to add edges. For example, the edge (b,f) from the original example will be missing with this implementation.

Comment: ah didn't read it correctly enough. You are right, then this approach is kinda pointless. Thanks for pointing it out.